# subset the data randomly based on the given conditions in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df as shown below.

df:

```
cust_id        nationality       group
1              indian            1
2              us                1
3              uk                1
4              indian            1
5              china             0
6              indian            1
7              us                1
8              indian            1
9              us                1
10             indian            0
```

in the above df 80% the customers are group 1. i.e 8 customers.
in that i would like chose 25% group 1 customers randomly without replacement.
i.e 25% of 8 =  2.

Expected output:

df_group1_25:

```
cust_id        nationality       group
1              indian            1
9              us                1
```

please note that the selection is random but it should be only from group 1 and 25% of group1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it always has to be `group == 1`, we can simply use `DataFrame.query` with `DataFrame.sample` with the `frac` argument:

```
df.query('group == 1').sample(frac=0.25)

   cust_id nationality  group
0        1      indian      1
6        7          us      1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with [pd.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html). My solution works if you want to make the selection for more than only one group:

```
df1.groupby(by="group").apply(lambda x: x.sample(round((25 * x.shape[0])/100))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
 cust_id    nationality  group
0   4       indian       1
1   7       us           1
```

For selecting one single group see Erfan answer!

Comment: is it always be group = 1

Comment: In this case group 2 is not selected because it has only two rows, and 25% of 2 is 0.5, which is rounded to 0

Comment: @DavideBrex It's works only for the given example, what if OP has more than 2 in group 2? Erfan posted an answer that gives correct results.

Comment: @Ch3steR Yes if he wants only a subset for one specific value (group == 1) then Erfan solution is the best way. However, my answer works if you want to select the 25% of the rows for more than only one group.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
dict = {'cust_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 
        'nationality': ['indian','us','uk','indian','china','indian','us',
                        'indian','us','indian'], 
        'group':[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict) 
  
df
```

To set up the dataframe.
Now to take a random sample of all group 1 entries:

```
# subset of group 1 entries
df_group_1 = df[df['group']==1]

# sample 25% of group 1 entries
sample_25_perc = int(0.25*len(df_group_1))
df_group_1.sample(sample_25_perc)
```

This returns the following:

[image]

Let me know if this helps!